# Stuck at boot screen, Nvidia graphics driver issues

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics, 20.04

I recently just built a desktop and want to run Linux on it, I've been using my laptop with Linux and have had no issues at all. I've done clean installs of Linux three times with the desktop. Everytime I install the Nvidia drivers and restart, it always fails to get to the login menu. I'm trying it with an RTX 2080 ti, does anybody know a solution to this? I don't want to have to do another Linux install but j also don't want to be using the open source drivers

Answer (score 2):

I am hoping from the tag that you are trying to install Ubuntu 20.04. It appears that the desktop GUI environment is not properly configured. You can try the following steps once booted into ubuntu.

1. Press `Ctrl+Alt+F1/F2/F3` to get to a terminal.
2. `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` to clean previous nvidia drivers.
3. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440` to fresh install the latest drivers.
4. `sudo apt-get install gdm` to reinstall Gnome desktop environment (or any other DE of your choice).
5. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`
6. `sudo reboot` to restart.